# If $K$ is a field, what is $K^1$? (notation)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

Let $K$ be a field. What does $K^1$ denote? I found this notation in the context of differentials, "Algebraic Curves, Algebraic Manifolds and Schemes" by Shokurov and Danilov, p. 102.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special $K$-module defined exactly on the cited page. It depends on the inclusion $k \to K$ which you have not mentioned. A more common notation is $\Omega^1_{K/k}$, this is the module of differentials. You can find a better treatment than in the cited book in every basic text on commutative algebra. See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differentials).